# How to return data in a react .map statement?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to use `warningItem` within my return statement in order to map some data into a react component.

I want to loop over `area` but have problems with syntax.

```
createWarnings = warningsRawData => {
    return warningsRawData.map(warningItem => {
        return (
            <div>
                <p className={styles.warningMainText} />
                <p>warningItem.area[0]</p>
            </div>
        );
    });
};
```

Comment: Assuming `styles` is defined somewhere, this seems to be fine. Maybe `warningItem` doesn't have the structure you think it has?

Comment: @FelixKling nope. i can reach my data before the second return via warningItem.area[0]. Inside the return... nothing.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "It does not get there though"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are missing the brackets around it.  Try:

```
createWarnings = warningsRawData => {
    return warningsRawData.map( (warningItem, i) => {
        return (
            <div key={i}>
                <p className={styles.warningMainText} />
                <p>{warningItem.area[0]}</p>
            </div>
        );
    });
};
```

Comment: Good catch... should be obvious though if `warningItem.area[0]` is literally printed on the page.

Comment: this works. I had a number of errors, but the i was a great addition. thnx!

Comment: @Spacemoose you're welcome :) I edited Elevine's answer to add that so it wouldn't have a warning of a missing key :)

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you loop to return elememnt in react, add `key` attribute is must. Else you will get warning.And add `{warningItem.area[0]}`

```
createWarnings = warningsRawData => {
   let values  =  warningsRawData.map((warningItem,index) => {
        return (
            <div key={index}>
                <p className={styles.warningMainText} />
                <p>{warningItem.area[0]}</p>
            </div>
        );
    });
    return values
}
```

;

Comment: What did you change and why?

Comment: I added key={index}. Else it will throw warring.

Comment: And you think because of the warning the element is not rendered? Or why else would this solve the OP's problem?

Comment: thnx. i ll check it out.